# How do I find the set of functions that would make this non-linear operator diverge?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, information-theory, entropy

I have this non linear operator
$$H(p) = -\sum_{n=0}^ {\infty} p_n ln(p_n)$$
where $p_n$ are given by a function $p(n)$ when $n$ is a whole number.

I want to find what set of $p(n)$ makes $H(p)$ diverge, but that also have the following properties:

- Decreasing monotonic
- Positive in x>0
- No singularities

Some examples of functions in this set are:

- $\frac{1}{x+1}$
- $\frac{1}{ln(x)}$
- $\frac{1}{x^a+1}$ where $0<a<1$

Working on this I have developed the following hypothesis:

- Any function that decreases faster than $\frac{1}{n+1}$ makes H converge. For example all functions of the form $1/n^a$ with a>1 converge to $0$ faster than $1/n$ and yet make $H$ converge. $H(1/n^3)\approx-0.59$
- Any function that decreases slower than $\frac{1}{n+1}$  makes H diverge.
- $\frac{1}{n+1}$  makes H diverge the slowest

I haven't been able to disprove these hypothesis, but I haven't been able to prove them either, I just keep finding more examples that support them.

One idea I had was to transform $H(p)$ into an integral, solve it, and then I would just have to see what $p(n)$ makes $H(p)$ diverge.

$$H(p)=-\int_a^b p(n) ln(p(n))$$

But when I try to use integration by parts I just get the same thing I started with.

I've also tried to turn this problem around:

$$J(p)=H(1/p)=-\int_a^b \frac{1}{p_n} ln(\frac{1}{p_n})$$

and try to look for functions that make $J(p)$ converge, but I have been equally unsuccessful.

Finally I've tried to find a function that tells me how fast $H(p)$ grows based on how fast $p(n)$ grows, given that I have reasons to believe this function grows as the growth of p(n) decreases until it reaches a maximum at $p(n)=\frac{1}{n}$ where it begins to decrease. But I haven't been able to find that function despite gleaming its behavior.

How can I prove or disprove my hypothesis?

Edit:

Since $\int_0^\infty log(x)dx$ diverges I think all I need is to multiply it by a function that also diverges in that range.
So my set would be the functions that:

- Decreasing monotonic
- Positive in x>0
- No singularities
- Diverges in $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$

Comment: Try $p_n=\dfrac{1}{n\ln n}$ and use Bertrand's series. Asymptotic behavior is not limited to $n^\alpha$. There is also the general Bertrand series, with $p_n=\dfrac{1}{n(\ln n)(\ln\ln n)\cdots(\ln\ln\cdots\ln n)}$ with a fixed number of factors in denominator. (to simplify I consider the sum starts at $n=n_0$ with a large enough $n_0$, what is interesting here is the behavior as $n\to\infty$). Also, according to your definition, any $p_n\to L>0$ would satisfy the condition. And your third point is absurd: any sequence converging more slowly to $0$ will make the series "diverge faster".

Comment: Thanks, you are right,  Asymptotic behavior is not limited to n^α, I didn't meant to imply that. Also, could you please explain me what $p_n \rightarrow L>0$ means?, I really don't get it. Finally, maybe I didn't state my third point correctly, what I mean is that while $1/n$ makes H diverge $1/n^a$ does not, for example with $H(1/n^{16})\approx-0.00017$. And since all $1/n^a$ with a>1 converge faster to 0 and yet make $H$ converge, I suspect that any function that converges to 0 faster than $1/n$ will too make $H$ converge

Comment: By $p_n\to L>0$, I mean $p_n$ converges to a value $L$ that is not zero (and I forgot to add, $L\ne1$). Then the series obviously diverges. I guess you want to restrict to the case $p_n\to0$.

Comment: And to answer the last part of your comment: no. I gave you a sequence $p_n$ (and even infinitely many using the generalized Bertrand series) that all converge to $0$ faster than $u_n=1/n$ (in the -usual- sense that $p_n/u_n\to0$), and which all make the series $H$ diverge. And of course that does not mean they are the only ones.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I wrote "fastest" instead of "slowest", I fixed that now. What I meant is that $1/n$ is the function that marks the division between functions that make H diverge and those that make it converge, $1/n$ being the "first" with this property and thus, the slowest

Comment: Again, no. *Any* sequence $p_n$ that converges to $0$ **slower** than $1/n$ makes $H$ diverge ($\sum p_n$ already diverges, and $\ln p_n\to-\infty$). And among those series that converge to $0$ **faster** than $1/n$, see my examples above. Not a boundary in either direction. However if you consider *only* $p_n=n^\alpha$, then you are right.

Comment: I finally get it, sorry, yeah, you are right

Comment: Side comment: the generalized Bertrand series is described on the Wikipedia article "[Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)". It gives Rudin's PMA as reference, but I believe I saw it in a book by Knopp, and it's probably in many places.

Answer (score 1):

'Anything slower that $(n+1)^{-1}$' is essentially $(n+1)^{-1+\epsilon}\quad(\epsilon>0)$, if I'm not missing something.

So plugging it in, and switch to integration:

$$
\begin{align}
-\sum_{n=0}^ {\infty} p_n \ln(p_n)&= -\sum_{n=0}^ {\infty} (n+1)^{-1+\epsilon} \ln(n+1) (-1+\epsilon)\\
&\ge -\int_1^\infty (m)^{-1+\epsilon} \ln m (-1+\epsilon) \mathrm dm\\
&= \frac{1+\epsilon}{\epsilon^2}
\end{align}
$$

Which tends to infinity as $\epsilon\to0^+$.

Comment: What about $\frac{\ln (n+1)}{n+1}$? Is this equivalent to $(n+1)^{-1+\epsilon}$ for some $\epsilon$?